# Finding root causes of performance issues from multivariate data

Tags: categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, causality

There are computer network nodes (routers, switches etc.) and there's data about their performance (CPU load, memory load, interface errors etc.). There are also variables about the nodes themselves - like which device *model* it is, its location, its operating system version etc.

Some nodes perform much worse that others. Is there a statistical technique which would point to the commonalities of the nodes which perform badly? The motivation here is that the commonality is often the *root cause*. Fixing the root cause would then improve the performance of the badly performing nodes.

For example, there's 10 nodes out of 1000 nodes that have CPU load twice higher than the other 990 nodes. What is common to these nodes in terms of their attributes like location, operating system version, etc.?

Some of the variables are categorical (location, operating system version), some are continuous (like CPU load).

Would principal components analysis or correspondence analysis apply here? I would really like to find out first before investing the time to understand and implement the method for this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you measure node performance? If it’s a continuous variable you could try multiple regression - each node will have performance as its response, and the various other attributes you mention as potential predictors. Fit the model and see what predictors are associated with low performance. If you have to categorize node performance as good and bad, then do the same using logistic regression.

I imagine you could also use other predictive techniques too,  decision trees, kNN etc

If you have multi-dimensional predictors (maybe location?) you can use PCA to reduce it down to a single variable, although this does make it more difficult to interpret the results.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful - nodes attributes are predictors and performance is response. Performance is measured as a continuous variable but can be also be categorized as good-bad. There are multiple potential predictors for each node - operating system version, location and node type. Does it mean I should first do PCA and then regression?

Comment: No, you don't necessarily need to do PCA - just try some kind of predictive analysis like regression. I only suggest PCA to convert predictors that are multi-dimensional into a single dimension e.g. if your "location" predictor was x and y coordinates, you could convert it to a single PCA axis.

Comment: Got it, thank you.

Comment: @rw2 Can you speak a little more to the [root cause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_cause_analysis) part of the question? I [searched for this term](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=root+cause+analysis) to find a statistical perspective on it.